# Adding test code into third-party modules in golang

Tags: go, github

I am new to golang. I understand most of the language quite well but not a lot of the *infrastructure* of the system.

I'm trying to learn the source code for a very large project that includes code from many different repositories on github. Usually, when I learn new source code, I compile print statements into the code so I can see what some of the variables are set to and see what source files and functions the executable is using. But I can't do that when there are so many different repositories. For example, consider this....

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "github.com/mainorg/mainproject"
    "github.com/organization2/projectA"
    "github.com/organization2/projectB"
    "github.com/organization3/project1"
    "github.com/organization3/project2"
)
```

I only have **mainproject** on my system, but all the other projects are required to compile the executable. I need to put a print statement in projectB to look at some thing going on in there. The first thing I tried was cloning projectB and then changing the import statement to the location where I cloned it, like this

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "github.com/mainorg/mainproject"
    "github.com/organization2/projectA"
    "../organization2/projectB"
    "github.com/organization3/project1"
    "github.com/organization3/project2"
)
```

But when I compile, I get this error.

```
"../organization2/projectB" is relative, but relative import paths are not supported in module mode
local import "../organization2/projectB" in non-local package
```

Is there a way to add some testing code into the other modules of this application and still be able to compile them from my local directory?

If not, is there some other way I could accomplish this using golang?

Comment: Have you looked into [workspaces](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces) ([tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces))? This will enable you to download `projectA` etc and have Go use the workspace copy (with you can modify).

Comment: 1. Never use relative imports. Never. 2. "Is there a way to add some testing code into the other modules" Basically no as this would be a major problem in securing the supply chain but Workspaces (see Brits comment) allow to do this. 3. The name of the language is Go.